# Owl Carousel is not taking component css in angular everything else is working fine

Tags: angular, frontend, owl-carousel

Owl Carousl is working fine. Everything is working. only Css from its component.css is not being taken by carousl nav. Please help me
everything is working fine css works fine in inspect browser but css  owl carousel is not taking  style from component css.

I have this in component html :

```
   <div class="bannerCarousel-wrap">
        <owl-carousel [options]="SlideOptions" [items]="images" [carouselClasses]="['owltheme','sliding']">
            <div class="item" *ngFor="let img of Images">
                <div style="align-content: center">
                    <img src={{img}}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </owl-carousel>
    </div>
//in ts 
Images = ['../../assets/images/2.jpg', '../../assets/images/2.jpg', '../../assets/images/2.jpg'];  

  SlideOptions = { 
    items: 1, 
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    navText: ["<img src = '../../assets/images/icons/slider_control_left.png'>", "<img src = '../../assets/images/icons/slider_control_right.png'>"],
   };  
  CarouselOptions = { 
    items: 3,
     dots: false,
      nav: true,
      navText: ["<img src = '../../assets/images/icons/slider_control_left.png'>", "<img src = 'images/icons/arrow_right.png'>"],
     };
```

in component css

```
 .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please proof read your post to make it more clear and review this link on how to ask good questions that get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try to add !important at the end of each style in the css file like 
.owl-carousel {
     position: absolute !important;
}

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `[ngClass]="{ item: true }"` instead of using a class, and then create your item class on the component CSS. After that, it should work for you.